# Почему в react-приложении вижу 404 статус после перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: reactjs, nginx

Настроил бэкенд GO, настроил фронтенд React, залил всё на сервер, настроил nginx.

Всё работает и бэкенд и фронтенд но после перезагрузки станицы пишет

[image]

Думаю проблема в настройках nginx

[image]

Как решить проблему ?

Comment: Вы явно не в том месте делаете настройки nginx! И 404 после перезагрузки указывает на кэш браузера. Делайте настройки по новой. И вместо конфига картинкой - текстом его в вопрос добавляйте!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на клиент-сайде [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) то все запросы должны ссыпаться в `index.html`. Добавьте в конфиг сервера

```
location / {
    try_files   $uri $uri/index.html /index.html =404;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с этой проблемой при выкладывании на Netlify. Оказалось что данных хостинг поддерживает настройку перенаправлений двумя способами: либо в виде отдельного файла с именем `_redirects`, либо как часть всего `netlify.toml` файла конфигурации.

Используя `_redirects` файл, который поместите в `public`:

```
/* /index.html 200
```

Я пробовал у меня сработало. В любом случае, ответ очевидный, нам нужна переадресация на `index.html`