# Приложение react запускается не на том порту

Tags: reactjs

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "(set PORT=3006 || export PORT=3006) && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Порт указан 3006, а по истоге пишет что запущен на 3000?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как поправить и как указать ip + port, чтобы приложение было доступным из вне.

Comment: попробуйте вот это решение https://stackoverflow.com/a/48669909, оно выглядит универсальным

Comment: `export PORT=4000 && react-scripts start` У меня так сработало, но как теперь сделать чтобы приложение было доступно из вне, то есть как в строчку добавить/указать ip?

Comment: 1) приложение стало доступно на http://localhost:4000? 2) опишите подробнее, для чего вам нужен этот "доступ извне"

Comment: Установил на удаленный сервер. То есть приложение не доступно из браузера. Локально мне его не открыть. Не понимаю, собираюсь на него сайт перенести...

Comment: надо сделать билд приложения и настроить что-то ([nginx](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1178764), [express+express-static](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1229233)), что будет его отдавать. если я сейчас сказал знакомые слова то попробуйте настроить, если нет - лучше посмотрите пару видосов про deploy reactjs-приложения, потому что объяснять с нуля это долго и лень

Comment: - Local:            http://localhost:5000
- On Your Network:  http://62.109.***:5000

Comment: Будь у меня локальный сервер, он бы открылся по http://localhost:5000. Собственно на сервер можно залить содержимое и закрепить домен. Но это извращенеи если так писать приложение. Каждый раз перезаливая.

Comment: Как разрабатываем проект, выполнить доступным по адресу 62.109.***:5000, не компилируя его...

Comment: запущенный на сервере разработчицкий инстанс будет слушать localhost. можно научить его слушать что-то другое, но это не нужно. нужно сделать/изучить то, о чем я написал в предыдущем комментарии.